# decltype and is_same giving confusing results

Tags: c++, types, decltype

Hi consider the use case below:

```
int main() {

    std::shared_ptr<int> shared_ptr_to_int;

    std::cout << typeid(int).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(*shared_ptr_to_int)).name() << std::endl;

    if (std::is_same<decltype(*shared_ptr_to_int), int>::value) {
        std::cout << "is same!\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "not the same!\n";
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

For my test case I am getting the result "not the same"

I'm not sure why its not resulting in value being true. Could somebody please explain to me what is going on?

PS: My ultimate goal is to compare the type stored within shared_ptr with another type (in this test case this type is int)

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: The result of the `decltype` is a reference type. Your implementation's `typeid` doesn't distinguish between that and a non reference.

Comment: Hi, for anyone who is going to mention to use the following:

std::is_same<std::shared_ptr<int>::element_type, int>::value

In the project I am working on I would not know that the type is int, thus the need for decltype. The second template argument for std::is_same is given by a templated function call where it can already be deduced and accessed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Introduction

When "dereferencing" — through `std::shared_ptr<...>::operator*` — a *shared_ptr* the result is a *reference*, this means that `decltype(*shared_ptr_to_int)` is equivalent to `int&`.

A *reference-to-int*  and *int* is not the same type, and as such you get the behavior which you are describing.

---

#### Elaboration

A *dereferenced* `std::shared_ptr` yields a *reference* so that one can actually reach in and modify the object that the *shared_ptr* is currently handling.

In order to fix your example you should use [std::remove_reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) to strip away that (potentially unexpected) *reference*.

```
if (std::is_same<std::remove_reference<decltype(*shared_ptr_to_int)>::type, int>::value) {
  ...
}
```

You could also pass `shared_ptr_to_int` as the operand of *decltype* and then use the result as qualifier to reach into `element_type`:

```
if (std::is_same<decltype(shared_ptr_to_int)::element_type, int>::value) {
  ...
}
```

---

#### Why does `typeid(...).name()` return the same *name* for both?

When `typeid` is invoked with a type which is a *reference* it will discard this and treat the *operand* as if it was a *non-reference* type (ie. it will simply throw away the `&`).

Something else worth mentioning is that the result from invoking `typeid(...).name()` is *implementation-defined* — one should never put too much trust into the returned value. The function might even return the same *name* for completely distinct types — there are literally no guarantees (from the standard's point of view).

**Further reading**:

- **[typeid operator - cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)**